# Unpacking a Hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wonder if there is any method which can unpack the hashes inside an array. For example

```
array = [{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}]
```

After unpacking it should give

```
array = [code: "404", code: "302", code: "200"]
```

I have tried using flat_map as follows

```
array.flat_map { |h| h.values } & array.flat_map { |h| h.keys }
```

But these are 2 separate arrays.

Comment: `[code: "404", code: "302", code: "200"]` is not a valid ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa. Agree But we can still get an array like that. It's just Altering the data.

Comment: One cannot get an invalid object.

Comment: Internally, `{:code=>"404"}` is the same as `{code: "404"}`. The only difference is the representation.

Comment: @jdno That doesn't mean that it is the same as `[code: "404"]`.

Comment: @Robin: You cannot have a hash that has multiple values for the same key (`code`).  The whole point of a hash is that when you give it one key, it looks up *one* value.  Maybe you want to make an array of all the different codes instead?  Or maybe you should ask a new question where you explain what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @David . I see what you are saying. Let's say I want it like
array = [code1: "404", code2: "302", code3: "200"]
Also updated the Question

Comment: Don't change the question. I rolled it back.

Comment: "Let's say I want it like array = [code1: "404", code2: "302", code3: "200"]" - that's not a valid Ruby array.

Comment: @Joe It is a valid Ruby array. Try yourself.

Comment: Yes, but what it really is is an array of a single element containing a hash: `[ { :code1 => '404', :code2 => '302', :code3: '200' } ]`

Answer (score 2):

For your updated version of the question, the answer's very straightforward:

```
array.reduce(&:merge)
```

[reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) is a method to iterate through an object and accumulate the values in some way. Using `&:merge` is shorthand for merging your hashes together.

The result of this gives you:

```
# => {:code1=>"404", :code2=>"302", :code3=>"200"}
```

Comment: What is `array` in this example?

Comment: @SagarPandya This was expressed in a comment where the original array has non-conflicting keys.

Comment: Did this work @Robin? Need anything else / anything clarifying?

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output `[code: "404", code: "302", code: "200"]` is not a valid ruby to declare an array having three elements. The actual outcome from the above would be an array having one single element:

```
[code: "404", code: "302", code: "200"]
(pry):39: warning: key :code is duplicated and overwritten on line 39
(pry):39: warning: key :code is duplicated and overwritten on line 39
#⇒ [{ :code => "200" }]
```

That is because one might omit curly brackets around hash when it introduces no ambiguity.

The best you can get is:

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  acc.merge!(h) { |_, v1, v2| [*v1, v2] }
end
#⇒ {:code=>["404", "302", "200"]}
```

Comment: Actually, that is not true.

Comment: @sawa well, this is a valid ruby producing the result one evidently does expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
array = [{:code=>"404"}, {:code=>"302"}, {:code=>"200"}]
[array.last] # => [{:code=>"200"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have changed your question, it has become clear that you basically just want to merge all the hashes into one hash.  You could do it with this simple loop:

```
m = {}
array.each do |h|
  m.merge!(h)
end
```

Ruby also provides a fancy way to do the same thing in one line:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |h, m| m.merge!(h) }
```

Oh yeah, I almost forgot.  You wrote your desired output with square brackets, which technically means that you are asking for an array that contains a hash.  The code above just gives you a simple hash.  In Ruby, we write arrays with square brackets and hashes with curly brackets, but the curly ones can be omitted in some cases.  There is no obvious reason to throw your hash into an array that just has one element, but if you really want to do that, then you can of course do it like this, assuming `m` holds the merged hash:

```
weird_array = [m]
```